# Different login screen now

Tags: macbook-pro, login-screen

My Mac's login screen is different from the normal one now and I am not sure why. My current login screen looks a little like this

[image: this]

as opposed to this

[image: this].

Any ideas as to why this has changed?

Comment: Have you opened/altered your [Keychain Access](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/what-is-keychain-access-kyca1083/mac) app?

Comment: @njboot no, not to my knowledge.